# I have a simple code which is not working. Cant fix the error "println"

Tags: java

I get a red line under "println". Cant fix this error only..I have tried, but cant make the code work ! any help would be appreciated

```
public class calculation {
static Double KG;
static Double Price;
static Double Calculate;
static Double Calculate2;
static String i = "5";
static String j = "9";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Result());
}

private static void Result() {
    KG = ((Double.parseDouble(i) + Double.parseDouble(j) +
          Double.parseDouble(j) + Double.parseDouble(j) + 
          Double.parseDouble(j)) / 10) * (Double.parseDouble(i + j) + 
          Double.parseDouble(i) + Double.parseDouble(i) + Double.parseDouble(i) +
          Double.parseDouble(i));

          Calculate = (Double.parseDouble(i) * 0.6);
          Price = (double) (6 + 5 / 60));
          Calculate2 = (KG / Calculate) - Price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Result()` method is declared as `void`, which means it doesn't return anything. As a result, `println()` is complaining since it needs some input to print.

Probably, you need to modify your program in some way, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Result(); // calculate values
  System.out.println(KG); // output KG value after it has been calculated
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to print the results of a method Result() but that method doesn't return anything so println() has nothing to print. Try returning something from Result() and your println should work.

Comment: ok :) I think I have understood it now.. tnx 4 the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Since `Result` returns void and there is no `System.out.println(void)` method, it will complain.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the method or write variable which you need to print.